# React: Prevent "flashing" of conditional render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a page in React that displays different things based on if the user is logged in or not. There is a state called "loggedIn" which is set to null, and in the return statement I create a ternary statement that renders different things based on loggedIn.

The problem is, the component renders, there is an observer that checks for the status of the authorization, and then sets loggedIn to true if user is logged in. This operations takes a small (but noticeable) amount of time. **So what happens is that when the user is directed to this page, there will be a brief flash of the component that renders when user is not logged in before the correct thing is rendered. Is there a way to prevent this brief "flash"?a**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import Fade from "@mui/material/Fade";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

export default function Welcome(props) {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
                // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
                console.log("Authorization granted.");
                setLoggedIn(true);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    navigate("/chat");
                }, 4000);
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                console.log("Not authorized.");
                setLoggedIn(false);
            }
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <Grid
            container
            spacing={0}
            direction='column'
            alignItems='center'
            justifyContent='center'
            sx={{ minHeight: "100vh", bgcolor: "background.default" }}
        >
            {loggedIn ? (
                <Fade in={true} timeout={3000}>
                    <Typography variant='h3'>Welcome! :'{")"}</Typography>
                </Fade>
            ) : (
                <Grid
                    container
                    spacing={0}
                    alignItems='center'
                    justifyContent='center'
                    sx={{ minHeight: "100vh", bgcolor: "background.default" }}
                >
                    <Typography
                        id='title'
                        variant='h3'
                        sx={{
                            padding: 3,
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                        }}
                    >
                        Nice Try
                    </Typography>
                </Grid>
            )}
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Comment: While checking on the client side there is nothing you can do. You have to wait for the API call to complete. Meanwhile it is a better practice to hide some data (maybe show a loader) and then when you have the info, then show the correct component

Comment: So there's 3 scenarios? null -> show loading, false -> show error, true -> show content, is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes. That gives a good UX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that when you render the `Welcome` component for the first time, the `loggedIn` state is always `null` (treated as *falsey* in that case), and will always take at least one more render before you're getting the logged in state, due to the async nature of your `onAuthStateChanged` function.

The simplest way is to have another state variable that manages the 'initial loading' state, i.e. it hasn't yet finished the auth check, and in that case, show some other loading state, a full screen spinner blocking spinner or something.  Similarly you could also do the same when your `loggedIn` state is `null` as that's its 'not yet sure' state from looking at your code, but personally I don't like having varying types on a boolean state like that, i.e. `boolean | null`

e.g.

```
loggedIn === null ? <LoadingSpinner /> : loggedIn === true ? /* Logged in state*/ : /* Logged out state */
```

Answer (score 1):

The component will render with the false statement first and it is noticeable when the auth does take an amount of time. What you can do is to wrap your app with auth context

```
import { useContext, createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isAuthReady, setIsAuthReady] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userChangedListener = onUserChanged((user) => {
      setIsAuthReady(true);
      setUser(user);

      if (!user) return router.push("/login");
      if (router.pathname.indexOf("login") !== -1) return router.push("/")
    });

    return () => {
      return userChangedListener ? userChangedListener() : null;
    };
  }, []);

  return <AuthContext.Provider
    value={{
      isAuthReady,
      user
    }}>
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>;
}

export const useAuthContext = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

And create a withAuth

```
import { useAuthContext } from "./authContext";

const withAuth = (Component) => {
  const Auth = (props) => {
    const { isAuthReady, user } = useAuthContext();

    return isAuthReady && user ? <Component {...props} /> : <LoadingComponent />;
  };

  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    Auth.getInitialProps = Component.getInitialProps;
  }

  return Auth;
};

export default withAuth;
```

Wrap the your page except for login with withAuth

```
export default withAuth(Welcome)
```

So with these steps, the page renders only when auth is ready, the time before the page renders, the loadingComponent will show